# How to send email automatically when tab button is pressed or "Assigned" value is given as input in Status Column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

```
  Name   |DateTask|Priority|Description|    Email    |Email Notify|Status 

Baishnav |01/05/20|High    |devlopment|dasr@gmail.com|   Yes      | Assigned
```

I have developed this platform on google sheets where I Have to create a Macro for sending emails to the corresponding person email Id if "Status" column is set as "Assigned" in Status column.

I have developed a code to pull out the macro function

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function macros() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G12').activate();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows =20;
  var count = 2;
  
  var dataRange = spreadsheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 7)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[0];
    var dateOfAssignment = row[1];
    var taskP = row[2];
    var td = row[3];
    var ts = row[6];
    var email = row[4];
    var isSent = row[5];
     
    
    if( ts == "Assigned"  && isSent != "Yes"){
      var message = "Hey" + row[0] + "\n Your assigned task on :"+ dateOfAssignment +"\n Task description " + td + "\n Regards Baishnav";
      var subject = "Sending emails from Spreadsheet";
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject,message);
      var cellstring = "G" + count;
      var tosetFlag = sheet.getRange(cellstring).setValue("Yes");
    }
    count++;
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a trigger like [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) ?

Comment: No, i barely know about macros, thats why

Comment: Did you move forward with this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your issue exactly. I completely redesigned a new function for you that works.
Don't forget to change the name of the sheet in my code **Sheet1** to your desired name.

Try this:

```
function sendEmail() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var sh_s = sh.getLastRow();
  
 var Name = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh_s).getValues().flat([1]);
 var DateTask = sh.getRange('B2:B'+sh_s).getValues().flat([1]);
 var Priority = sh.getRange('C2:C'+sh_s).getValues().flat([1]);
 var Description = sh.getRange('D2:D'+sh_s).getValues().flat([1]); 
 var Email = sh.getRange('E2:E'+sh_s).getValues().flat([1]); 
 var isSent = sh.getRange('F2:F'+sh_s).getValues().flat([1]);  
 var Status = sh.getRange('G2:G'+sh_s).getValues().flat([1]);     
   
  for ( var i=0 ; i < Name.length ; i++){
  
    if (Status[i]=='Assigned' && isSent[i] != "Yes"){
    
    var message = "Hey" + Name[i] + "\n Your assigned task on :"+ DateTask[i] +"\n Task description " + Description[i] + "\n Regards Baishnav";
    var subject = "Sending emails from Spreadsheet";
    MailApp.sendEmail(Email[i], subject, message);
      
    sh.getRange(i+2,6).setValue('Yes');  
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: @MariosKaramanis What if it is not the last row being changed? I think the OP could use the help of a `onEdit(e)` trigger, and then tweak your sendEmail into sendEmail(e) with its corresponding logic, to catch the row that was just changed.

Comment: @Aerials improvements can definitely be made. The script that the OP has provided (which he didn't explain what works and what does not) is based on a static data logic. I could rebuild a new project for him based on an onEdit function but this is not what stackoverflow is. He should provide his efforts towards this direction first. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are right, I though of mentioning it to you to add to your answer since you already went ahead and "completely redesigned something that works".

Comment: Indeed that is true, unfortunately I don't have time to do it now. Feel free to use my code and provide an onEdit solution and I will vote up immediately :) I am sure the OP will benefit from this as well.